# Cannot upload CSV file to Parse Data Browser

Tags: javascript, csv, parse-platform

I am trying to upload my CSV data to the data browser of my Parse app. The file is processed successfully by Parse but when I try to "Save Schema", I get the error, "Something went wrong, Try again".
I have tried converting my CSV to UTF-8 character encoding but the error is still there. Any ideas what is causing the issue?

Comment: Could you share your CSV file?